# create new columns on pandas based on one column elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column like this:

```
    column_1                    
0   0.25 / 0 / 0.25 / -0.25     
1   -0.25 / 0 /1                
2   0 / -0.5 / -0.25            
3   1/ 0.25 / -0.75
```

each row is made of chain of consecutive numbers (separated by /)
I want to create 2 new column, and keep only the first element and the last element, like below example

```
    column_1                     new_column_1st_element   new_column_last_element
0   0.25 / 0 / 0.25 / -0.25      0.25                     -0.25
1   -0.25 / 0 /1                 -0.25                    1
2   0 / -0.5 / -0.25             0                        -0.25
3   1/ 0.25 / -0.75              1                        -0.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df['new_column_1st_element'] = df.column_1.str.split('/').str[0]
df['new_column_last_element'] = df.column_1.str.split('/').str[-1]
```

Output

```
                  column_1 new_column_1st_element new_column_last_element
0  0.25 / 0 / 0.25 / -0.25                  0.25                    -0.25
1             -0.25 / 0 /1                 -0.25                        1
2         0 / -0.5 / -0.25                     0                    -0.25
3          1/ 0.25 / -0.75                      1                   -0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `column_1` has data in string datatype

```
df['new_column_1st_element'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['column_1'].split('/')[0], axis = 1)
```

Similarly this can be done for the `new_column_last_element`

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) along with the given regex pattern:

```
df[['first', 'last']] = df['column_1'].str.extract(r'([^/]+).*?([^/]+)$')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

column_1                    first     last
0  0.25 / 0 / 0.25 / -0.25   0.25    -0.25
1             -0.25 / 0 /1  -0.25        1
2         0 / -0.5 / -0.25      0    -0.25
3          1/ 0.25 / -0.75      1    -0.75
```

You can test the `regex` pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/Ou3pTN/1).